# Converting Relational databases to flat and vice-versa

Tags: python, relational-database, non-relational-database

I'd like to write a script to convert from a relational database to a flat one and vice-versa. The database's rows mostly contain data from text input, but there are a few dropdown lists from the form that enter the primary IDs of a row from another table. Currently I have database rows that would look like say:

(1, 4, 2, 45.508582, -73.610102, 3) that I want turned into:

(1, Sherbrooke, "Park Frontenac", 45.508582, -73.610102, John, Doe) and this back to the above.

Some tables contain one column per primary ID (like city and park tables), but others have 2 or more (like the persons table).

What's the easiest way to write a script for this? I'm not comfortable with scripting outside of basic php, although I plan to start learning python soon.

Comment: Depending on the number of tables you have, denormalising your database (making a relational database a flat file) could make the database size explode. What's the rationale behind this?

Also, where's your database stored at the moment (Access? MS SQL? MySQL? something else?) and what format do you want to convert to (Excel? CSV? tab-delimited?)

Answer (score 0):

Make SQL-query for that gives needed data

```
select name1, name2, number1, number2
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.t1_id
```

and using sqlalchemy will create and run your script

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('user_pass_address_port')
dbc = engine.connect()
dbr = dbc.execute(sql)
for row in dbr:
    print row
```

each row would be have tuple with needed data